# Joining three tables for exeuting data in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a logic where I want to join three tables for fetching the data as and when required. The common column in all three tables is `CHANGEREQUESTID`

Also, I have one Master table and other two are child tables. Below is their information

```
select * from CHANGEREQUESTS  where CHANGEREQUESTID = 9665;  (Master Table)
select * from TBL_PRE_POST_HOTO where CHANGEREQUEST_ID = 9665; (Child Table)
select * from TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO where CHANGE_REQUEST_ID = 9665; (Child Table)
```

Now what I want is

> There could be chances that there might not be data in 2nd or 3rd table for particular `CHANGEREQUEST_ID` but there will be always data in first table ie(Master Table)

Here is table desc

```
Table 1 (Master)
Name                        Null     Type           
--------------------------- -------- -------------- 
CHANGEREQUESTID             NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)   
CHANGETYPEID                NOT NULL NUMBER(10)     
NETWORKTYPE                          VARCHAR2(50)   
STATENAME                            VARCHAR2(50)   
CITYNAME                             VARCHAR2(50)


Table 2

Name              Null Type            
----------------- ---- --------------- 
ID                     NUMBER(18)      
SAP_ID                 NVARCHAR2(50)   
R4GSTATE_CODE          NVARCHAR2(20)   
CHANGEREQUEST_ID       NUMBER(18)      
HOTO_STATUS            NVARCHAR2(50)   
CREATED_BY             NVARCHAR2(100)  
CREATED_DATE           DATE


Table 3

Name                                              Null Type           
------------------------------------------------- ---- -------------- 
ID                                                     NUMBER         
REPLACMENT_NEW_SITE_NET_BUDGET_REQUIRMENT              NUMBER(20)     
NEW_SITE_TOWER_CONSTRUCTION_COST                       NUMBER(20)     
NEW_SITE_FIBERIZATION_COST                             NUMBER(20)

CHANGE_REQUEST_ID                       NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
```

**After MTO's answer**

Here is my updated query

```html
SELECT cr.CHANGEREQUESTID as "CHANGE REQUEST ID",cr.CHANGEREQUESTNUMBER as "CHANGE REQUEST NO", (select CHANGETYPE from CHANGETYPES ct where cr.CHANGETYPEID = ct.CHANGETYPEID) AS "TYPE OF CHANGE",
      cr.NETWORKTYPE AS "NETWORK TYPE", cr.STATENAME as "STATE NAME", cr.CITYNAME as "CITY NAME", cr.DESCRIPTION, cr.CREATEDBY as "CREATED_BY", cr.CREATEDON AS "CREATED DATE", cr.LASTMODIFIEDBY as "LAST MODIFIED BY", cr.LASTMODIFIEDON as "LAST MODIFIED DATE",
      (select STATUS from APP_WF.WF_STATUS st where cr.STATUSID = st.STATUS_ID) AS "CURRENT STATUS", cr.BAND, 
      
       pph.SAP_ID as "SAP ID", pph.LATITUDE, pph.LONGITUDE, pph.SAP_ID_TYPE AS "SAP ID TYPE", pph.SAPID_REMARKS "SAP ID CREATION REMARKS", pph.CREATION_SAPID as "CREATED SAP ID", 
        pph.CREATED_BY as "CREATED BY", 
        pph.APPROVED_BY as "SAPID APPROVED BY", pph.APPROVE_REJECT AS "APPROVE REJECT REMARKS", pph.APPROVED_DATE as "APPROVED DATE",
        pph.REJECT_REMARKS as "SAPID REJECT REMARKS",  pph.REJECTED_BY as "SAPID REJECTED BY", pph.REJECTED_DATE as "REJECTED DATE",
        
       ce.SAP_ID as "SITE REPLACEMENT SAP ID", ce.DELETION_SITE_SAPID as "DELETION SAP ID", ce.RCOM_ID_NEW_SITE as "RCOM ID NEW SITE", ce.NEW_LATITUDE as "NEW LATITUDE", 
       ce.NEW_LONGITUDE as "NEW LONGITUDE", ce.REMARKS as "REMARKS", ce.CREATED_BY as "SITE REPLACEMENT CREATED BY",
       ce.APPROVE_REJECT as "SAP ID Approved/Rejected By", ce.APPROVED_BY as "SITE REPLACEMENT APPROVED BY", ce.APPROVED_DATE as "SITE REPLACEMENT APPROVED DATE",
       ce.REJECT_REMARKS as "SITE REPLACEMENT REJECT REMARKS", ce.REJECTED_BY AS "SITE REPLACEMENT REJECTED BY", ce.REJECTED_DATE AS "SITE REPLACEMENT REJECTED DATE ",
       CASE cr.STATUSID
       WHEN 825 THEN 'Close' ELSE 'Open' END AS "CMP STATUS"       
FROM   CHANGEREQUESTS cr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_PRE_POST_HOTO pph
       ON (cr.CHANGEREQUESTID = pph.CHANGEREQUEST_ID)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO ce
       ON (cr.CHANGEREQUESTID = ce.CHANGE_REQUEST_ID)
AND cr.createdon >= TO_DATE ('07-02-2024', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
AND cr.lastmodifiedon <= TO_DATE ('14-02-2024', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
ORDER BY cr.LASTMODIFIEDON DESC;
```

Comment: what is wrong with joining them by CHANGEREQUEST_ID ?

Comment: @nbk: nothing wrong, but what if there is no data in second table or sometime in third table then ?

Comment: use LEFT JOIN for both child tables

Comment: How many rows can each query return separately? 0-1, 0-N?

Comment: @TheImpaler: Except the **master table**, other tables can return more than 1 rows..

Comment: Please provide a few rows of sample data and the expecte result.

Comment: A traditional join will generate the cross product of both child tables. How exactly do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT cr.*,
       pph.column_that_you_want1,
       pph.column_that_you_want2,
       cedi.column_that_you_want3,
       cedi.column_that_you_want4
FROM   CHANGEREQUESTS cr
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_PRE_POST_HOTO pph
       ON (cr.CHANGEREQUESTID = pph.CHANGEREQUEST_ID)
       LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO cedi
       ON (cr.CHANGEREQUESTID = cedi.CHANGE_REQUEST_ID)
WHERE  cr.CHANGEREQUESTID = 9665;
```

Comment: Will it work if there is no data in second or third table ?

Comment: @hud I am sure you can test it and find out for yourself. (If you cannot then the answer is: yes, the columns where there is no data in the `OUTER JOIN`ed tables will output `NULL` values).

Comment: I have used ur join, but not getting all values from the third table, its coming as null, I am updating the question

Comment: @hud I have no idea what an "ur" join is; you should use an `OUTER JOIN`. If the values exist in the outer joined tables then they will be displayed; you have not shared any sample data so replicating your issue is, at the moment, not possible.

Comment: Thanks, with minor change it worked. Appreciate your efforts for making me understand the logic

Answer (score -1):

Select *
From changerequests AS cr
Left Join TBL_PRE_POST_HOTO AS pph ON cr.changerequestid = pph .changerequest_id
LEFT Join TBL_CMP_EMG_DATA_INFO AS cedi ON cr.changerequestid = cedi.change_request_id
WHERE cr.changerequestid = 9665;